# NextJS call gtag("event") from api route

Tags: javascript, typescript, server, next.js, gtag.js

I'd like to log an event on Google Analytics when an api route is opened.

My gtag implementation is as follows at the moment:

```
export const logEvent = ({ action, category, label, value }: LogEventProps) => {
  (window as any).gtag("event", action, {
    event_category: category,
    event_label: label,
    value: value,
  });
};
```

Problem is that it relies on a window for logs to be fired, which is undefined, understandably so, whenever I'm calling this method from an `api` route.

I couldn't find any valuable information on how to log an event from the server side.

A work-around might be to have the api redirect to a blank page that logs the event, but I don't love the idea and wonder if there's a better approach.

Comment: While technically you could use the [Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/reference) to send such events, is there a reason why you couldn't send the events from the client?

Comment: yes, because the api redirects to another link, which is not owned by me

Answer (score 0):

The window keyword(Variable) is only available on the client side. you can't use window variables on the server side. Windows variables depend on the browser's information. meanwhile, gtag saved his information in window variable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).